# I want to make a GUI similar to XCODE collapsible accordion style grouping mechanism of the inspector

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa programming :  I want to make a GUI similar to XCODE collapsible accordion style grouping mechanism of the inspector.

Comment: Remember, folks, just because somebody doesn't have any idea of how to proceed doesn't mean their question is invalid.

Comment: @PeterHosey: I didn't vote on this, but I'll just point out that 1) technically this isn't even a question, and 2) for someone to expect others to do his/her research without showing the least bit of effort on his/her own part can be considered as a bit rude.

Comment: @Michael: #1 is just grammatical pedantry. As for #2, research requires knowing what to look for, and effort requires knowing what to work toward. If you have *literally no idea*, the only thing you can do is ask. Getting offended by that amounts to “how dare you not know the first thing about what you need to do!”, which is rude in itself.

Comment: @Jarrod: this is a perfectly fine question. I would have worded it differently, but I want the same. I like the inspector-style in XCode and I wonder whether anybody did this before me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can require 10.9, try [NSStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000741-TRANSLATED_CHAPTER_965-10_9StackView).

Otherwise, you'll need to make a custom view that contains:

- One heading view for each section

  - A disclosure triangle
  - A borderless text button (also clickable)
  - In fact, the entire header row should be a button, really
- One main view for each section

  - Not initially a subview of the inspector view
  - Show each view by adding it as a subview
  - Hide each view by removing it from its superview (the inspector view)
  - Optionally keep only one view shown at a time by hiding (removing) any other views when showing any view

You should probably have an NSViewController for each section, with its `title` being the section's title (used in the section's header view) and its `view` being the section's main view (the one that gets put into and taken out of the inspector view).

Comment: Very nicely answered I have succeeded to dynamically load nib files inside NSViewController, a step in the right direction. I am an experienced windows + web programmer and new to cocoa and Mac OS X, I have never felt a language/framework difference like that before, I feel the impact reaching my ancestors. so expect more stupid questions from my behalf!, I have found a framework called inspector-kit,I could not make it work,I concluded that it is old and not compatible with latest version of xcode 4, Am I right ?

Comment: @RaidenCore: That's one possible reason out of many.